# What were the 3 crirical experiments and the argument given by Ampere which helped in determining the magnetic field made by electric current?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

In The Feynman Lectures on Physics volume 2, [Magnetostatics](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_13.html), section 13-4 Mr. Feynman tells us that there were *"three critical experiments and a brilliant theoretical argument given by Ampère"* that helped in determining the the magnetic field by a steady current. However he says he is going to skip those and come directly upon the results.

Can you please tell me what were those 3 experiments and that argument by Ampere. Thank you.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on [History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).